# GNU Parallel facing silent exit and invalid option error

Tags: linux, rhel, gnu, gnu-parallel, amazon-linux

I tried performing the full installation from: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

The installation was successful. It's working well when installed on Mac OS but on Amazon Linux (RHEL64) I am facing below issues:

1. On running just `parallel` the command exits silently.

   ```
   dev-dsk % parallel
   dev-dsk %
   ```
2. On running **any** command even `parallel --version` gives following error:

   ```
   dev-dsk % parallel --version                                               
   parallel: invalid option -- '-'
   parallel [OPTIONS] command -- arguments
       for each argument, run command with argument, in parallel
   parallel [OPTIONS] -- commands
       run specified commands in parallel
   ```

   Same error with running `parallel --gnu`.

IMO, there is no conflict with **NO** conflict with **Tollef's** parallel of moreutils package as moreutils doesn't exit on my machine.

How to make GNU Parallel work on RHEL64?

Comment: Note that the `man` page does not prove there's no conflict.  I don't know what shell you use, but with `bash` you can run the command `type -path parallel` and it'll tell you what version of `parallel` you are running.

Comment: The error you get is exactly the output you get when you run moreutil/Tollef's `parallel`. So probably you somehow have that installed in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it was not working as for me there was just one executable named parallel in my system path.

**But I was able to fix it as below**:

1. Run `whereis parallel`. This gives all the paths where executables named **parallel** is present. For my case there was just one path `/usr/local/bin/parallel`. Running using this path works just fine.
2. You can add an alias for this in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file like `alias parallel='/usr/local/bin/parallel'`

And now `parallel` works like charm.

```
dev-dsk % parallel --version         
GNU parallel 20190322
Copyright (C) 2007-2019 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.
```

Comment: That’s not a packaged version of parallel, if it is in /usr/local/bin.  You (or someone else who administers your computer) must have installed it from source or some other method.

Comment: Yes I installed that as clearly said in the question.

Answer (score 1):

TL; DR: `apt install parallel`

At least on Debian Buster and Bullseye, /usr/bin/parallel is provided by the packages `moreutils` and `parallel`. Having only moreutils installed I found the same behaviour as the OP. Installing `parallel` solves this. Whatever.